# Why Laravel Error "Show ID for Update" how to solved?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I just tried laravel, i get an error message like this :

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property namauser of non-object enter code here
```

My Models :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
class UserModels extends Model
{
    protected $table = msusers
}
```

MyControllers :

```
public function showedit($id)
{
$edit = DB::table('msusers')->find($id);
return view('user.edituser', compact('edit'));
}
```

MyRoute

```
Route::get('edit/{id}', [UserController::class, 'showedit']);
```

MyView :

```
<input type="text" name="nama" class="form-control" id="nama" value="{{ $edit->namauser }}">
```

Comment: In showedit controller before return -> dd($edit);

Comment: Another hand, you have UserModels, but you use DB::table etc..

Comment: $edit = DB::table('msusers')->find($id);
        dd($edit);
        return view('user.edituser', compact('edit'));

show is null or value is null

What happend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `firstOrFail()` to avoid ids that do not exist.

```
public function showedit($id)
{
    // Will throw 404 error if id is not found in msusers table.
    $edit = DB::table('msusers')->where('id', $id)->firstOrFail();

    return view('user.edituser', compact('edit'));
}
```

But a better fix would be using Route model binding.

```
Route::get('edit/{edit}', [UserController::class, 'showedit']);
```

```
use App\Models\UserModels;

public function showedit(UserModels $edit)
{
    return view('user.edituser', compact('edit'));
}
```

Comment: findOrFail is bad method call .

Comment: And using Route model binding 404 not found

Comment: I got mixed up with firstOrFail. I edited the answer. If the model wasn't found, does it exist in the database? It's looking for a row with id = {edit} in the table msusers.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand

Comment: Does `firstOrFail` work? What's the structure of the table `msusers` ?

Comment: I have tried it and the results are not found in 404, can you write the script
Please comment with your code form my code

Answer (score 0):

Your table name should be a string. you have forgotten add a semicolon as well

Following line

```
protected $table = msusers
```

should be

```
protected $table = "msusers";
```

Corrected code.

```
<?php
namespace App\Models
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
class UserModels extends Model
{
    protected $table = "msusers";
}
```

edited :
Lets move to namauser issue

in your controller do a dd() and see whether you get any data or not also check the parameter $id

```
public function showedit($id)
{
   $edit = DB::table('msusers')->find($id);
   dd($edit); //Check whether you get any data or not ;
   return view('user.edituser', compact('edit'));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this my models

<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserModels extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'msusers';
}

Comment: The value displayed is null
add add ($ edit);

Comment: Most probably it should be related with the ID.Check your database Manually for the record. (Make sure you are passing correct record